Awswrangler raising an "ArrowNotImplementedError: Nested data conversions not implemented for chunked array outputs" on parquet read
Unable to read parquet file from AWS S3 using awswrangler (AWS SDK for Pandas) 3.7.2 as it raises an Arrow not implemented error.
Example code:
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_parquet('s3_uri/file.parquet', use_threads=True)

Raises error:
File ~/miniconda3/envs/vibrancy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awswrangler/_utils.py:178, in validate_kwargs.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
    175 if condition_fn() and len(passed_unsupported_kwargs) > 0:
    176     raise exceptions.InvalidArgument(f"{message} `{', '.join(passed_unsupported_kwargs)}`.")
--> 178 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/vibrancy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/awswrangler/_config.py:715, in apply_configs.<locals>.wrapper(*args_raw, **kwargs)
...
File ~/miniconda3/envs/vibrancy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/_parquet.pyx:1675, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.read_all()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/vibrancy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowNotImplementedError: Nested data conversions not implemented for chunked array outputs

The original parquet file was written to S3 using the awswrangler to_parquet method.

Some issues on github about this, not sure if that has been fully resolved e.g. https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/21526 suggests reducing group size below 2 GB.

I am not fully sure about your case, but I faced with this error while reading pandas parquet with pandas.
It seems that your dataframe has nested dtypes – like a column full of lists.
An example of nested structure in df column. Pandas has historically been designed around flat, tabular data structures. As an alternative, I used the Polars library. Polars is built from the ground up with Arrow integration in mind.
import polars as pl
path = '/path/to/df.parquet'
df = pl.read_parquet(path)

